# Jenkins : bash script ran with nohup is neither working nor writing anything to log

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, jenkins, nohup

**BACKGROUND**

I would like to explain the scenario properly here.
I am running  **jenkins_2.73.3** in my cloud server with **ubuntu 16.04**.
Currently, there are **3 users** in the server:

- root
- develop-user *(which I had created for many reasons such as test,deploy etc)*
- jenkins *(which was created by jenkins ofcourse, I also added this jenkins user to sudoers group)*

**PROBLEM**

I have a **bash script** that I am calling from a build step in `Jenkins`. Within this **bash script**,there is a `nohup` command for calling a separate `deployScript` in the background such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup deployScript.sh > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

After the build step is completed, I see that a id is generated inside `save_pid.txt` but `app.log` is surprisingly empty. I can't kill any processes with this generated `pid`. So, that means there isn't any process created in the first place here. Also, the `deployScript.sh` does not seem to have any effect at all. It's just not working. This happens everytime I run the build in Jenkins. I can assure that there is nothing wrong with the `deployScript.sh`.

I have tried running this **bash script** with the `develop-user` manually without Jenkins and it works perfectly. Contents are written to the `log file` and also I can use the generated `pid` to kill the process. I have also tested this in my local environment and it works.

**QUESTION**

I have been looking at this for days. What might be the root cause here ?Where can I look into to see some logs or other info ? How is the `pid` generated whereas the `log` file is empty ? Is it a `permission` issue with the jenkins user ? Please help.

Comment: You sure $WORKSPACE is set ok?

Comment: Maybe redirect input from `/dev/null`: `nohup < /dev/null > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>& 1 deployScript.sh`? Else have you checked that `$WORKSPACE` has the correct value and `deployScript.sh` is executable and can be found on the command search `$PATH` at the point where it is invoked?

Comment: @Nic3500, Yes, I think so. When the build step ran, 'app.log' was automatically created in the WORKSPACE, but it was empty.

Comment: Is `echo $! > save_pid.txt` on a new line?

Comment: Can you test without `nohup` (like `deployScript.sh > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1`) and with an other script (`nohup echo "Jenkins test $(date)" > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 `)?

Comment: @WalterA `echo $! > save_pid.txt` is on the same line.  I tested with `nohup echo "Jenkins test $(date)" > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1` and it works !! I could see the output written `$WORKSPACE/app.log`. And also please note that the `deployscript.sh` is actually inside a folder within the $WORKSPACE. So, its actually `$WORKSPACE/some_path/deployscript.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to be a permission issue and also the script wasn't executable I guess as pointed out in the comments above.

So, now the bash script looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chmod a+x deployScript.sh
sudo nohup deployScript.sh > $WORKSPACE/app.log 2>&1 & echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line inside the execute shell in jenkins to run it in background without the process being killed.

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe <command> &
```